# Plot is not done correctly when shape is specified along with facet_grid in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please pardon me, if this turns out a very silly question. I have been busting myself since last 12 hours wondering what am I doing wrong.

I am trying to get a plot using facet_grid and shape in ggplot2. I am using shape to display points differently for different years. The actual data set has data points for 7 years. Sample code data is representative of the actual data with only 3 year. The plot is correct when I don't use shape. It displays the points under the right years on x-axis. Once shape is used in the aes part, the data points are not under proper years.

Please help me with this issue. Sample code reflects the problem

I am using R 2.14.0 and ggplot2 0.9.3.1 on ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

tr_week = c(
  "2006-01-16", "2006-01-16", "2006-01-16", "2006-01-16", "2006-01-16",
  "2006-01-16", "2007-02-19", "2007-02-19", "2007-02-19", "2007-02-19",
  "2007-02-19", "2007-02-19", "2009-08-24", "2009-08-24", "2009-08-24",
  "2009-08-24", "2009-08-24", "2009-08-24"
)

tenor = c(
  "T00-09", "T10", "T11-14", "T15", "T16-29", "T30", "T00-09", "T10", "T11-14", "T15",
  "T16-29", "T30", "T00-09", "T10", "T11-14", "T15", "T16-29", "T30"
)

weeklyTrades = c(
  18, 87, 50, 206, 233, 114, 28, 49, 106, 122, 51, 59, 57, 82, 17, 26, 53, 42
)

tr_year = c(
  "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007",
  "2007", "2007", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009"
)

tr_week = as.Date(tr_week, "%Y-%m-%d")
tenor = factor(tenor)
dfWeek = data.frame(tr_week, tenor, weeklyTrades, tr_year, stringsAsFactors=F)


##### The following plots correctly #############
p = ggplot(dfWeek, aes(tr_week, weeklyTrades, group = 1)) +
    ggtitle("Weekly Trades per Tenure Bucket") +
    xlab("Trading Week") + ylab("weekly Trades")

    p +
    facet_grid(tenor ~ ., scale = "free_y") +
    geom_point(alpha=0.5, size=1.5)

###### The plot is wrong as soon as shape is specified
q = ggplot(dfWeek, aes(tr_week, weeklyTrades, group = 1, shape = factor(dfWeek$tr_year))) +
    scale_shape_manual(name = "Year", values = c(15, 3, 17, 4, 5, 16, 6)) +
    ggtitle("Weekly Trades per Tenure Bucket") +
    xlab("Trading Week") + ylab("weekly Trades")

    q +
    facet_grid(tenor ~ ., scale = "free_y") +
    geom_point(alpha=0.5, size=1.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is due to fact that when defining `shape=` you use `factor(dfWeek$tr_year)` - so points get shapes in the order as they are in vector `dfWeek$tr_year` and not the order as they are plotting taking into a count other variables you set in `aes()` and `facet_wrap()`. In `ggplot()` call you already have stated that you will use data frame `dfWeek` so you don't need to write it again in `aes()`.

To get correct plot use inside `aes()` just

```
shape = factor(tr_year)
```